# Are wave files better candidate for steganography than mp3?if so then why?

Tags: mp3, wav, steganography

I read about wav file format and found too many projects of steganography based on it but didn't found that much projects based on mp3 though it is found more frequently on web than wav.

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that mp3 has lossy compression and the steganography techniques are more complex. In the same way that jpegs are more widespread, yet everyone learns the lsb substitution technique as their first method.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming, but about cryptography. The question might be more on-topic on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks Reti43 i got some idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wav format is uncompressed audio with no formatting headers. You can change a few bits in this format without significantly affecting the audio; you will not break the file format and a listener will not be able to tell the difference between the original file and the modified one.

The mp3 format is compressed audio. If you change bits in mp3, you run risks:

1. You modify a header and the audio no longer plays back
2. You modify the audio, and a listener can tell the file is weird. The audio is compressed, so changes in the audio data get magnified upon decompression.

Comment: thanks.so basicaly mp3 files are compressed only during creation and data if entered in last bit of frame it wont be lost during transferring file over web????

Comment: The compressed data don't necessarily correspond to the raw audio signal, so changing the compressed data could result to massive changes in the audio signal up to outright corrupting it. You need to understand how mp3 encodes information first.